# Menu For Side Order Didn't Pop

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

After user choose their pizza,they can't choose their side order as the menu for side order are missing.

Is there anything wrong with the looping?

It is suspected to have something to do with while looping.

```
int main()
{
int cont;
int cust;
int i;
int j;
double side=0.00;
double pizza=0.00;
double total=0.00;

for(cust=0;cust<5;cust++)
{
    printf("Welcome To Pizza Hut\n");
    printf("Pizza Menu :\n");
    printf("1=Chicken\n");
    printf("2=Meat\n\n");
    printf("Enter Pizza Flavor : ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    if(i==1)
    {
        pizza=5.50;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        pizza=4.50;
    }

    while(cont==1) /*This is where the menu for side order didn't show*/
    {
        printf("Side Order Menu :\n");
        printf("1=coke\n");
        printf("2=pepsi\n");
        printf("3=bread\n");
        printf("4=salad\n\n");
        printf("Enter Side Order : ");
        scanf("%d",&j);

        if(j==1)
        {
            side=1.50;
        }
        if(j==2)
        {
            side=1.30;
        }
        if(j==3)
        {
            side=2.50;
        }
        if(j==4)
        {
            side=2.60;
        }

        printf("Add Order? (1=yes||0=no) : ");
        scanf("%d",&cont);
    }
  }

total=pizza+side;
printf("Total : %.2f",total);
cust++;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, is cont == 1 ?

Comment: int cont;//initialized to 0

Comment: It's a local, so it's not initialized to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have the line `int cont;`, replace it with `int cont=1;`. `cont` will have indeterminate value, so you'll never enter the loop to set it to anything else.

Comment: Not if it's automatic storage, it doesn't.

Comment: If it's that helpful, consider accepting it (click the tick next to it), as that's the done thing here if an answer answered your question. @JazliPa

Answer (score 3):

Here, you haven't given a value to the cont variable so while loop doesn't properly work.

Comment: thank you..I forgot to assigned the starting value for variable cont..my mistake

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some errors:

1. You should initialize the cont variable to 1
2. You should to add a breaking mechanism inside your while loop in order to escape from it
3. You should reset your cont variable to 1 after the while loop again.

This might should work:

```
int main()
{
int cont = 1;
int cust;
int i;
int j;
double side=0.00;
double pizza=0.00;
double total=0.00;

for(cust=0;cust<5;cust++)
{
    printf("Welcome To Pizza Hut\n");
    printf("Pizza Menu :\n");
    printf("1=Chicken\n");
    printf("2=Meat\n\n");
    printf("Enter Pizza Flavor : ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    if(i==1)
    {
        pizza=5.50;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        pizza=4.50;
    }

    while( cont == 1 ) /*This is where the menu for side order didn't show*/
    {
        printf("Side Order Menu :\n");
        printf("1=coke\n");
        printf("2=pepsi\n");
        printf("3=bread\n");
        printf("4=salad\n\n");
        printf("Enter Side Order : ");
        scanf("%d",&j);


        if(j==0)
        {
            cont = 0;
            break;
        }

        if(j==1)
        {
            side=1.50;
        }
        if(j==2)
        {
            side=1.30;
        }
        if(j==3)
        {
            side=2.50;
        }
        if(j==4)
        {
            side=2.60;
        }

        printf("Add Order? (1=yes||0=no) : ");
        scanf("%d",&cont);
    }

    cont = 1;
  }

total=pizza+side;
printf("Total : %.2f",total);
cust++;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, when you say

```
while(cont==1)
```

You're saying, while cont it's equals to 1, proceed, and cont is never 1.
You have to initialize the variable count to 0 too.

Comment: yeah right..I forgot to assigned its value..thanks @dacastro4